# repeater foreach in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a website in ASP.Net, using MVC, and need to list a set of results
but i get error in the code

model:

```
public class Customers
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Customers> Itemlst { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
    public ActionResult List()
{
     Customers itemobj = new Customers();

     return View(itemobj);
}
```

view:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Itemlst)
{
     <tr>
          <td>Items ID:</td>
          <td>@item.ID</td>
          <td>Items Name:</td>
          <td>@item.Name</td>
     </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: The message would be helpful, but I can see you have a circular reference in Customers.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And what does the first part of your view look like (@model <something>)?

Comment: I guess your `Itemlst` is null so you have NullReferenceException when trying to iterate it.

Comment: NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Resultat.ExecuteAsync() in Resultat.cshtml
+
@foreach (var item in Model.Itemlst)

Answer (score 1):

From the `NullReferenceException` that you are receiving we can see that the issue is because of the `Itemlst` not being initialised. One of the ways to solve this is just to make sure that there is a valid list when you create the object:

```
public class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
      Itemlst = new List<Customers>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> Itemlst { get; set; }
}
```

So you can add values to the list in your action if need:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
     Customers itemobj = new Customers();

     var example = new Customers ();
     example.Id = 1;
     example.Name = "Example";

     itemobj.Add();
     return View(itemobj);
}
```

I don't know if you are just using this as an example for your question, but I can't help but notice that there is something weird. You could use something different like:

```
public class ViewModel // Name to what makes sense to you
{
    // Some other properties...

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
} 

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or you could just use `List<Customer>` as your model in the view directly (yes, your model can be a object which is simply a list of objects).

Comment: thanks for the answers but the problem is that i want to get value from the form

Comment: Well, @johnsmith... this question is about "need to list a set of results but i get error". And it makes sense for the code that you posted, that is just trying to show values. Getting values from the form (from the user?) would be a whole different question, so I suggest you to first check if you can list (using this or any other answer) and then create a new question here.

Answer (score -2):

When you pass the Customers list to the view, this list itself is the model.

Change Model.Itemlst —> Model inside the foreach loop.

This will iterate the list of customers.