# asp.net mvc repeater using foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building a website in ASP.NET MVC, and I need to save the value of a form in table so I used foreach as repeater but I get an error

> NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet. AspNetCore.Views_Home_Resultat.ExecuteAsync() in Resultat.cshtml + @foreach (var item in Model.Itemlst)

Model:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> Itemlst { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
     Customers itemobj = new Customers();

     return View(itemobj);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Itemlst)
{
     <tr>
          <td>Items ID:</td>
          <td>@item.ID</td>
          <td>Items Name:</td>
          <td>@item.Name</td>
     </tr>
}
</table>
```

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="resultat" method="post" runat="server">
    <div class="form-style-5">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ID :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="Id" required />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="Name" required />
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="resultat" value="show solution" />
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [repeater foreach in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214255/repeater-foreach-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: you're loading resultat.cshtml but have a method called List. Is it even going to the List method, where you aren't initializing the object? Or to your Resultat method? The method and view name should be the same.

Comment: How do you populate the `Model`?

Comment: FROM the controller

Comment: You're not initializing the Itemlst. that's what the error is telling you. in your `list` method, you're still not initializing the collection. You say you're doing it in comment on the answer but then You're not showing us the right code. `List` is not the name of the view being loaded. Resultat is. Where is your Resultat() method

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the `Itemlst` as shown below:

```
public class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
        Itemlst = new List<Customers>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> Itemlst { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @johnsmith change <td>@item.ID</td> to <td>@item.Id</td> and try again.

Comment: please give a better detail from the view.cshtml file. How do you receive model in the view?